# Declaring a function prototype in a brace

Tags: c, scope, function-call, function-declaration, function-prototypes

In 'The C Programming Language(2nd)' 71~72p,

> Second, and just as important, the calling routine must know that **atof** returns a non-int value. One way to ensure this is to declare **atof** explicitly in the calling routine.

And the code right under the paragraph including above part.

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define MAXLINE 100

/* rudimentary calculator */
main()
{
    double sum, atof(char []);
    char line[MAXLINE];
    int getline(char line[], int max);

    sum = 0;
    while (getline(line, MAXLINE) > 0)
        printf("\t%g\n", sum += atof(line));
    return 0;
}
```

A function prototype is declared at top in general. But why the function prototype `double atof(char[])` is declared in the main()? I've never seen like that although I am a novice.

Comment: It doesn't really matter where you declare it. It just needs to be declared before you use it.

Comment: Because that's *"One way to ensure [the calling routine knows that atof returns a non-int value]"*, per the quote.

Comment: Aka "(How to abuse) The C programming Language". You might want to read a different book with less focus on how to not write code. Since this code is 100% horrid. `atof` shouldn't be used in the first place because of its error handling, use `strtof` instead, always.

Comment: @Lundin I think you mean `strtod` in this case.

Comment: @Lundin I've always seen a praise about this book. You are a first person that gives another point of view. The book is good for me as it always say why. And It's interesting for me. This talk may not be allowed in SO, can you give me a reference link about the prefix (How to abuse) or its detail?

Comment: @opol I made it up just now, but the book is very much outdated and the coding style used is harmful and hard to follow. And it teaches you to rely on poorly-specified behavior since it was written prior any standardization and the conversion to C90 in 2nd edition was sloppily made. Anyone who writes things like `double sum, atof(char []);` in a book meant for teaching C, shouldn't be teaching C, period. Anyone who writes stuff like that in production code will get fired.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For starters in early versions of C you may call a function without declaring it before the function call. In this case by default it was supposed that the function has the return type int.

Pay attention to that in general a function declaration does not necessary provide the function prototype.

Compare these two function declarations

```
int f();
```

and

```
int f( void );
```

The first function declaration means that you can say nothing about the number and types of the function parameters.

The second declaration is indeed a function prototype that means that the function does not have parameters.

So if within a program there is a function call and you are using an old compiler then it is assumed that the function has the return type `int`.

To say the compiler that the function has a different return type you need to declare the function before the function call.

You may declare a function in the file scope or in a block scope in which the function is called.

This function declaration

```
double sum, atof(char []);
^^^^^^      ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

that  at the same time is the function prototype is placed in the outer block scope of main though you could place it before main. In the last case the function prototype would be visible for the entire module.

It would be more correctly to declare the function like

```
double atof( const char [] );
```

because usually such a function does not change the passed string as an argument.

Also bear in mind that there is a standard C function with the same name declared in the header `<stdlib.h>`.

```
double atof(const char *nptr);
```

Comment: "You may declare a function in the file scope or in a block scope in which the function is called." This helped me a lot. And I want to ask one more question about this. If a function prototype is declared outer than the function, then whether the function prototype is located before or after the function is not important? For example, is a structure  `void main(void) { {function declaration;} function prototype declaration;}` valid?

Comment: @opol It is important to declare a function before its call. Moreover the current C Standard does not allow to call a function when its declaration is unknown.

Answer (score -1):

It's an old way of declaring a function prototype